# Can't install software due to broken isc-dhcp-server dependency

Tags: networking, software-installation, uninstall, dhcp

while trying to setup hotspot i have messed up with the dhcp server setting , i do not know what went wrong but i am getting following error while installing anything :

Errors were encountered while processing:
 isc-dhcp-server
 dhcp3-server

please help me to reset the setting to defaults as it were on a fresh ubuntu install.

following is the error while updating firefox :

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%%
(Reading database ... 10%%
(Reading database ... 15%%
(Reading database ... 20%%
(Reading database ... 25%%
(Reading database ... 30%%
(Reading database ... 35%%
(Reading database ... 40%%
(Reading database ... 45%%
(Reading database ... 50%%
(Reading database ... 55%%
(Reading database ... 60%%
(Reading database ... 65%%
(Reading database ... 70%%
(Reading database ... 75%%
(Reading database ... 80%%
(Reading database ... 85%%
(Reading database ... 90%%
(Reading database ... 95%%
(Reading database ... 100%%
(Reading database ... 526048 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace firefox 27.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (using .../firefox_28.0+build2-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement firefox ...
Preparing to replace firefox-globalmenu 27.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (using .../firefox-globalmenu_28.0+build2-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement firefox-globalmenu ...
Preparing to replace firefox-locale-en 27.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (using .../firefox-locale-en_28.0+build2-0ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement firefox-locale-en ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up isc-dhcp-server (4.1.ESV-R4-0ubuntu5.9) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript isc-dhcp-server, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing isc-dhcp-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dhcp3-server:
 dhcp3-server depends on isc-dhcp-server; however:
  Package isc-dhcp-server is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing dhcp3-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up firefox (28.0+build2-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
Please restart all running instances of firefox, or you will experience problems.
Setting up firefox-globalmenu (28.0+build2-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
Setting up firefox-locale-en (28.0+build2-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 isc-dhcp-server
 dhcp3-server
Error in function: 
Setting up isc-dhcp-server (4.1.ESV-R4-0ubuntu5.9) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript isc-dhcp-server, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing isc-dhcp-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dhcp3-server:
 dhcp3-server depends on isc-dhcp-server; however:
  Package isc-dhcp-server is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing dhcp3-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

below is the output of `sudo apt-get install -f`

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
[sudo] password for parashar: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  liblaunchpad-integration1.0-cil libboost-iostreams1.46.1 libtommath0 openjdk-7-jre-lib
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 36 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up isc-dhcp-server (4.1.ESV-R4-0ubuntu5.9) ...
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript isc-dhcp-server, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing isc-dhcp-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of dhcp3-server:
 dhcp3-server depends on isc-dhcp-server; however:
  Package isc-dhcp-server is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing dhcp3-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 isc-dhcp-server
 dhcp3-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please add the rest of the error in your question, we need it to help you!

Comment: i have added the rest of the error as in case of updating firefox

Comment: And aslo post the output of `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: i have added the output of the sudo apt-get install -f

Answer (score 2):

this solved my issue :

```
sudo apt-get purge  dhcp3-server    
sudo apt-get purge isc-dhcp-server
```

Comment: did you try the above solution?

Comment: yes as it was giving error in both  isc-dhcp-server and  dhcp3-server so i purged both ,initially everyone was suggesting to reinstall or purge only one of them so it was not working